# diagonalization problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It's too easy question but I'm confused.

Let A matrix is \begin{pmatrix}
        5 & 4\\
        4 & 5\\
        \end{pmatrix}

Of course it can be diagonalized since it has distinct two eigenvalues.

The question is to find square roots, that is $R^2$=A.

I think there are two possible $R$, $A^\frac{1}{2}$ and $-A^\frac{1}{2}$

However the answer is four.
What are the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues, and both of them have two square roots.

Comment: Two eigenvalues are 1 and 9, so their square roots are 1 and 3. But the combinations are only two cases, (1,3) (-1,-3). Is is possible to combine (-1,3) (1,-3)? I tried but they can't make it.

Comment: @email: Yes, there are four combinations as you said. What is your problem?

Comment: Oh, I made some calculation error. Now I find four combinations. Thanks!